# RelativeLayout Button Creation

Tags: android, button, onclick, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to create buttons after i press a button ( this one is premade in XML ).
The thing is, i can do this in LinearLayout however when i switched to RelativeLayout everytime my buttoncreator method runs it deletes the previously created button and creates a new one.

to be more spesific;
My buttoncreator method

```
public void buttoncreator(String name,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position,RelativeLayout layout){



    positionrandomer(position);
    final Button dummybutton = new Button(this);
    dummybutton.setText(name);

            //these are here for test,it works but still i have the same problem

    position.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button1);
    position.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button2);

    dummybutton.setLayoutParams(position);

      layout.addView(dummybutton);
      return;

}
```

(position randomer is a method where it sets random margins ).

The place where i call creator method

```
Button luckbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

                luckbutton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                name="Blue";
                buttoncreator(name,position,layout);
                name="Blu4e";
                buttoncreator(name,position,layout);





                                                            }
                                                                           });
```

so, my intent is to create 2 buttons on 1 buttonclick, however it creates only 1. ( actually, it creates the first one then deletes it and creates the second one ).

Appereantly there is something i don't understand with RelativeLayouts,
What i am doing wrong?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you a workaround to do the thing you want. Why don't you create your buttons in your xml file and set their visibility in your `onCreate()` to `View.GONE` and in button's `onClick` you set their visibility to `View.VISIBLE`. I think this will do the thing that you want and I don't think you will have problem with `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer,however these buttons has to be non-predefined due to the codes purpose :/.  
This simply works verywell in LinearLayout, why does it act this way in Relativelayout?

Comment: Actually I'm pretty sure that It's creating the both buttons. The thing with RelativeLayout is that you have to set `layout_below/layout_above` params to align the views. If you don't do that, they will be stuck in same position, that's why you think that it's creating only the second button. Try to set the text of your first to something longer like : `gdvasjdhaskdhajdhasj` and you will see that it will stay under the second button.

Comment: Done, yep i have tried it and you're right about that. I'll be back when i fix the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: i can't answer my own question for 8 hours so im writing it here 
Thanks for Android-Droid, 
The problem was Setting Margins are not that affective in positioning for stuff in relative layout.

In order to solve this i've nested a linearlayout in main relativelayout, and made positioning in that.

Main code stays the same just changed Relative's to Linear and Nested a Linearlayout in XML

Thanks a lot!